# gnome-session-flashback desktop -- is just booting into gnome enough or do I need to uninstall unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, performance

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04. If I want to run Ubuntu with a less performance-sucking GUI than Unity, is it enough for me to [install gnome-session-flashback desktop](http://www.howtogeek.com/189912/how-to-install-the-gnome-classic-desktop-in-ubuntu-14.04/) and set the system to boot into gnome, or must I also remove Ubuntu desktop?

I assume the answer is 'yes' (for the non-pragmatist logicians out there I refer to the former clause, not the entire sentence), since the only desktop which affects performance is the one which is actually booted into, but I want to make sure since my understanding of the inner workings of these things is unfortunately a little poor. I have no space problems on the HDD, so I have no problem keeping Unity as long as it does not get in the way of the performance of the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

Reboot and select your Gnome by clicking the Ubuntu sign before logging in. I think Gnome Metacity might be the right choice for you.

Comment: I do understand how to install it (I did link to instruction, after all). My question is whether running that session is sufficient, performance-wise, or whether I have to remove e.g. the previously installed unity as well. Can I interpret your answer as 'this is all you have to do'?

Comment: @NickTheSwede This is all you have to do. The don't influence each other and they have no consequences for your performance.